# How to ensure that you are building against STLport

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stlport

I am using Visual C++ 2005 to build a couple of libraries and an executable.
I include the STLport location in the Additional Include Path of the libraries and include the library in the input to linker for executable.

The library however seems to reffer to stl symbols (such as string) without the stl port namespace.
This results in a linker error.

these are the relevant lines from the command line on the 2 libraries and executable:

```
/Od /I "..\Junctions\fo_fid_3rdParty\STLport-5.1.0\stlport"

/Od /I "..\Junctions\Includes\fo_fid_3rdParty\STLport-5.1.0\stlport"

/OUT:"..\ET_BUILD\vc8\Debug\bin\SFGWDealerwebFixAutorecD.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO 
..\junctions\libs\fo_fid_3rdParty\STLport-5.1.0\lib\stlportstld_vc8.5.1.lib
```

Here is an example of an error.
    Error   7   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool      __thiscall Springfield::CClientFramework::ProviderRequest(class      std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &)" (?ProviderRequest@CClientFramework@Springfield@@UAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@00@Z)    FixAutorec.lib

This symbol Springfield::CClientFramework::ProviderRequest comes from a library ClientArchitecture.lib
This is how dumpbin.exe displays this symbol:
    (public: virtual bool __thiscall Springfield::CClientFramework::ProviderRequest(class stlpd_std::basic_string,class stlpd_std::allocator > const &,class stlpd_std::basic_string,class stlpd_std::allocator > const &,class Springfield::IDataStoreNode const *))

Note that the symbol being looked for defines its strings std::basic_string.
Whereas the destination defines symbols as stlpd_std::basic_string.

thanks

Comment: Could you post the code for a short program (on the order of 'hello world') that shows the problem along with the exact error messages?  That way we can see what the linker should be looking for and what it's actually complaining about.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use STLPort?

Comment: The libraries I am linking against seem to have been built using STLPort.